# Агрегация дохода с когорт за месяц и за год

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы:

- `users` с полями:

  - `user_id`,
  - `reg_date`,
  - `country`
- `purchases` с полями:

  - `id` (id платежа),
  - `amount` (сумма платежа),
  - `user_id`,
  - `created` (дата платежа)

Нужно дополнить запрос так, чтобы вместо колонки revenue получить 2 колонки «30d revenue» и «360d revenue» — доход с когорты за месяц и за год. Но с датами я прям завис совсем.

Вот мой на половину написанный запрос:

```sql
select date_format(u.reg_date, '%Y-%m') as 'cohort',
       u.country,
       count(u.user_id) as 'new_users',
       sum(p.amount) as 'revenue'
from users u
left join purchases p on u.user_id = p.user_id
where date(u.reg_date) >= '2019-01-01'
group by date_format(u.reg_date, '%Y-%m'), country
having revenue > 0
```

*left join тут используется чтобы не потерять количество пользователей, т.к. надо будет считать ARPU из них, учитывая и не платящих.

Comment: `sum, iif/case, date_add/sub` - ключевые слова для решения задачи

Comment: так, вроде отдельно каждый оператор разобрал, но логику к запросу всё равно не могу придумать, даже просто словами :)

Comment: вам надо просуммировать `sum(` если `iif(`, дата покупки < дата регистрации + месяц `date_add`, то `amount`, иначе 0 `))`

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо :)

Comment: дак и оформите ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upd. Получился вот такой запрос:

```sql
select date_format(u.reg_date, '%Y-%m') as 'cohort',
       u.country,
       count(u.user_id) as 'new_users',
       sum(if(date(d.created) < date_add(date(u.reg_date), interval 1 month), amount, 0)) as '30d revenue',
       sum(if(date(d.created) < date_add(date(u.reg_date), interval 1 year), amount, 0)) as '360d revenue'
from users u
left join purchases p on u.user_id = p.user_id
where date(u.reg_date) >= '2019-01-01'
group by date_format(u.reg_date, '%Y-%m'), country
having revenue > 0
```

Всё работает как надо, спасибо @teran